# Firebase Crashlytics iOS Privacy Settings

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, privacy

I am trying to provide Apple with the new required privacy disclosures.

I don't track anyone or send any information off device.

I do use Google Firebase Analytics and Crashlytics. I currently have the AdSupport linked for analytics (though thinking of removing that in the future). I really only need the Crashlytics reporting for quality assurance.

I am thoroughly confused after reading the exhausting thread at [Firebase Analytics: New Apple Privacy Guidelines](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5928)

And even more confounded from the official privacy [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/app-store-data-collection).

I don't understand why the guide speak is so abstract and doesn't use terminology that Apple's privacy settings. For instance, is the data collected linked or "not linked to your identity?"

Google has made something that should be simple as a couple screenshots a complete mystery. eg "If you are using Analytics with AdSupport use these base settings"

Can anyone show me what it should look like? My best guess is:

[image]

Comment: Did you figure this out eventually? I'm this close to removing Analytics and Crashlytics from my apps because Google is being so vague and unhelpful.